# Smartfield - Control Type Dropdown - sending Parameters to OData

Tags: sapui5

the details of what I am using are:

- SAPUI5 Version 1.7
- OData from Gateway Service, ***no*** from CDS View.

I have a ***Master-Detail*** and a ***Smartform*** in Detail view. This view (Detail) present the info of an Entity Type - a plain structure, no a deep-structure.

I draw a *`Smartfield`* with a control Type as *Dropdown* and it works smoothly, the description of the key is displayed and so on... ***but***, I would need to send 2 values from the same Entity Type/structure as parameter to fetch the displayed values in the Dropdown. I checked the event *`innerControlsCreated`* and I think I can do something here but I don't know how I could send the values as Filter.

Any suggestions? Thanks!